# OpenGL in Win32 - is wglCreateContext a must?

Tags: windows, opengl

Every tutorial on OpenGL in Win32 I read instructs to use the `wgl` functions, `wglCreateContext()` and `wglMakeCurrent()`.

Is this the only way of doing OpenGL in a Windows environment?

Are these functions part of the OpenGL API or the Window API?

Answer (score 2):

> Is this the only way of doing OpenGL in a Windows environment?

Yes, aside from getting a library like GLFW to do it for you (and take care of the cross-platform issues).

> Are these functions part of the OpenGL API or the Window API?

The Windows API.

OpenGL specifies some semantics of OpenGL contexts (that they can be created, made current to the thread, and are required for any OpenGL commands to work), but does not specify an API for them, so it is system dependent. Windows has `wglCreateContext`, and Linux has `glXCreateContext`

Comment: A side question: does this have anything to do with GLEW? Does `glewInit()` call wgl functions?

Comment: @Pilpel GLEW is simply a convenience library for calling `wglGetProcAddress` for each extension function. So yes, GLEW does use the wgl API.

Comment: I see. But it doesn't use wglCreateContext or wglMakeCurrent. Right?